# My string returns a certain number despite changing the string

Tags: c++, string, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to make a program that takes a string formed out of natural numbers and calculates their sum. Things like `1+4`, `43+986`, etc.

This is the code:

```
char s[100] = "39+72+15";
int main()
{
    while(strlen(s) != 0)
    {
        i = 0;
        while((s[i] != '+') && (s[i] != '-'))
        {
            temp = temp * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
            i++;
        }
        cout << "temp = " << temp << endl;
        strcpy (s, s + i + 1);
        temp = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, no matter what string value I enter:

[image]

It turns the last number from the string into `1877688504`, regardless of the last number in the string.

I'm sure that the rest of the string is empty so there's not any junk in it that could cause the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: how does your inner `while` stop when parsing the last number?

Comment: Your inner while does not stop on end of string.

Comment: Why not tokenize the input string first, and then loop through the tokens? Split `"39+72+15"` into `"39"` `"+"` `"72"` `"+"` `"15"`, and then process each token as needed (`atoi()`, `operator+`, etc). Also, you are clearly using C++ (`cout`, etc), so why are you using C functions (`strlen()`, `strcpy()`) to process the string instead of C++ functionality (`std::string`, `std::istringstream`, etc)?

Comment: this is C in C++ sugar coating (`cout`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a check for the end of the string in your inner while loop.

Currently you check for either + or - but the last number will not have a plus or minus after it.

Changing

```
while((s[i] != '+') && (s[i] != '-'))
```

to

```
while((s[i] != '+') && (s[i] != '-') && s[i] != '\0') // '\0' is string terminator
```

should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a crude **`C++`** way of tokenizing the algebraic expression:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>

int main()
{
  std::string ex = "39+72+15";
  std::queue<std::string> operand_stack;
  std::queue<std::string> operator_stack;

  // tokenize
  size_t ppos = 0;
  size_t cpos = 0;
  for (auto i = ex.begin();; ++i) {
     if (*i == '+' || *i == '-') {
        cpos = i - (ex.begin() + ppos);

        std::string operand = ex.substr(ppos, cpos);
        ppos = cpos + 1; // skip operator
        operand_stack.push(operand); // push integer operand

        std::string op(1, *i);
        operator_stack.push(op); // push operator: "+" or "-"

     } else if (i == ex.end()) {
        ppos = i - (ex.begin() + ppos) + 1; // skip operator

        // get last operand
        std::string operand = ex.substr(ppos, ex.length() - ppos);
        operand_stack.push(operand);
        break;
     }
  }

  // Assuming L->R, same precedence
  while (! operator_stack.empty()) {
     std::string op = operator_stack.front();
     operator_stack.pop();

     int lhs = std::stoi(operand_stack.front());
     operand_stack.pop();

     int rhs = std::stoi(operand_stack.front());
     operand_stack.pop();

     if (op == "+") {
        operand_stack.push(std::to_string(lhs + rhs));
     } else if (op == "-") {
        operand_stack.push(std::to_string(lhs - rhs));
     }
  }
  std::cout << "sum = " << operand_stack.front();
}
```